# Unable to bind 2 tables to viewModel and send to view

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, data-binding, viewmodel

table 1. MerchantBusiness
table 2. MerchantServices

i want to display both tables data in a single view.

I want to display the MerchantBusiness details on the view. very basic business name, address etcc.

the MerchantServices is a list of services that the business has.

so i first created the viewModel

```
Public Class MerchantServicesModel

Public Property MerchantViewModel() As Merchant
    Get
        Return _Merchant
    End Get
    Set(value As Merchant)
        _Merchant = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Merchant As Merchant



Public Property ServiceViewModel() As IEnumerable(Of MerchantService)

    Get
        Return _Services
    End Get
    Set(value As IEnumerable(Of MerchantService))
        _Services = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Services As MerchantService

End Class
```

and in my controller im binding the two tables to the viewModel

```
Function Index(id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim db As New MerchantEntities

    Dim MerchantDetails As New MerchantServicesModel
    MerchantDetails.MerchantViewModel = db.Merchants.Find(id)

    MerchantDetails.ServiceViewModel = (From m In db.MerchantServices
                           Where m.MerchantID = id
                           Select m).ToList()


    Return View(MerchantDetails)


End Function


My View

@ModelType MerchantServicesModel 

@Code

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"

End Code


@Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.MerchantViewModel.BusinessName)

@For Each item In Model.ServiceViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) item.ServiceName)

Next
```

i was thinking that the MerchantBusiness is not a full list just details of the particular business
but the MerchantServices is a IEnumerable list so i create a table and style blah blah..

now the error im getting is

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VBClassMVC.MerchantService]' to type 'VBClassMVC.MerchantService'.

am i missing something, or am i binding incorrectly?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hay all i manged to fix that. Here is the updated ViewModel

```
 Public Property ServiceViewModel() As IEnumerable(Of MerchantService)

    Get
        Return _Services
    End Get
    Set(value As IEnumerable(Of MerchantService))
        _Services = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Services As IEnumerable(Of MerchantService)
```

i needed to add IEnumerable(Of MerchantService) to the _Services Private variable..